# Apparent FTL speeds seen by observer

Tags: general-relativity, reference-frames, time-dilation, faster-than-light, observers

MY guestion is if I was in a ship orbiting a black hole (not very close to the event horizon) I am orbiting pretty far and I am experiencing that my time is slowing down realitive to people on earth. Let's say the ratio is 60 to 1 which means for every one second I experience a person on Earth experiences 60 seconds. Now let's say humanity launchs a spaceship going to alpha centari about 4 light years away at only 0.1 C. I wanna watch this momentious step for humanity so I pull out a telescope and observe the spaceships movement. What happens? Do I see an apparent velocity of 6C due to my time dilation which would mean to me the trip would look like it takes less than a year? If so does that apply that apparent ftl speeds are possible by mulipulating time dilation?

Comment: If you look in the sky, you'd see stars rotating around the Earth. Alpha Centauri makes a circle of 4.3 light years in radius over 24 hours. This is 10,000 times the speed of light already without a black hole.